# How to search for a string in files with name containing a specific string in linux?

Tags: linux, string, file, search

I want to search recursively for "MY:STRING" string in files whose name contains "20121218" in them, the output should give me the file name and location. Search should look in files under sub-directories as well.

Comment: Use [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` and `grep`:

```
find . -type f -name '*20121218*' -exec fgrep -l "MY:STRING" {} \;
```

---

Explanation:

`find` the command find.

`.` start looking in the current directory.

`-type f` only interested in files.

`-name` filename match against `'*20121218*'`

`-exec` execute the following command on the files found.

`fgrep` fixed string grep.

`-l` print only filenames that contain a match.

`{}` the list of matched files from `find` command.

`\;` delimiter.

Edit:

```
$ find . -type f -mtime -18
```

Comment: Thanks. This is website has angels. I love it.

Comment: And what if I want to search for the string in files whose creation date is after 01 December? In this search I don't care about the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Use recursive `grep` as shown below. There is no need for `find`.

```
grep -Flr --include="*20121218*" "MY:STRING" /path/to/dir
```

Since, you are searching for a fixed string instead of a regex, use the `-F` option to speed it up.

Comment: And what if I want to make the same search for the string in files whose creation date is after 01 December? In this search I don't care about the file name.

Comment: You need to use `find` with the `mtime` option then.

Comment: Is there a similar speed up option for `find`?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use:

> find . -type f ( -name '*20121218*' ) -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -n MYSTRING

...which will show you the file path, name, and line number (with color) everywhere MYSTRING is located within files containing 20121218.

EX. from my Android Kernel source:

> find . -type f ( -name '*config*' ) -print0 | xargs -0 grep --color -n MSM8974

returns many, but here is a few:

> ./arch/arm/mach-msm/Kconfig:254:config ARCH_MSM8974
>
> ./arch/arm/mach-msm/Kconfig:255:  bool "MSM8974"
>
> ./arch/arm/configs/g2-kddi-perf_defconfig:41:CONFIG_ARCH_MSM8974=y
>
> ./arch/arm/configs/g2-kddi-perf_defconfig:44:CONFIG_MACH_MSM8974_G2_KDDI=y
>
> ./arch/arm/configs/lgl22_defconfig:314:CONFIG_ARCH_MSM8974=y
>
> ./arch/arm/configs/g2-open_com-perf_defconfig:503:CONFIG_MACH_MSM8974_A1=y
>
> ./arch/arm/configs/g2-open_com-perf_defconfig:516:CONFIG_SND_SOC_MSM8974=y

Comment: and of course use -iname instead of -name if you want to search both upper and lower case strings.